# Test a method throws a specific exception .NET

Tags: unit-testing, exception, mstest, assert

How to test that a void method throws a specific exception in .NET.

I have a method that throws 3 different types of exceptions depending on inputs. How would I test that I get the current one each time, AND ALSO test that it doesn't throw any when passed with the correct inputs.

Thanks!

Comment: The one built into Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [NUnit](http://www.nunit.org), you can use the `Assert.Throws()` method to test for a specific exception being thrown.

Comment: Please explain the downvote. My answer is correct if NUnit is being used; information which was not initially given by the OP.

Comment: Initially the OP didn't specify what unit testing framework they were using, so my answer is valid if they were using NUnit. Since they only specified the unit testing framework after my answer was given, I should not be penalized for that.

Answer (score 12):

Example in [MSTest](http://mvwood.com/blog/8789/)

```
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(StackOverflowException))]  //Update for your expected Exception Type
public void TestThatExpectsAnExceptionToBeThrown()
{
   // Test code here...
}
```

This requires no assert. If the expected exception is thrown, the test will pass. If not, you've got a failing test. Obviously with the code snippet above you'd substitute the exception type for the type of exception you wish to test for.